# Grunt-bower not copying files to correct destinations

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I'm running Grunt 1.0.1, bower 1.7.9, and grunt-bower 0.21.1

When I run the grunt task bower:dev, which should pull main files from bower and put them into a directories. All the files are ending up in the  main destination directory. The extension specific directories are being ignored. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');
grunt
    .initConfig({
            bower: {
                dev: {
                    js_dest: 'target/js',
                    css_dest: 'target/css',
                    dest: 'target/bower_components',
                    base: 'bower_components'
                }

            }

        }
    )
```

};

bower.json

```
 {
  "name": "springangulardemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "appPath": "src/main/webapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-aria": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-messages": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: With npm, bower, and grunt I feel like I have to repeat myself a lot. I want to define my dependencies once. Then have a mechanism to move them into place for the front end. It seems like I need a few pieces together to make this work.

Comment: I just read through the plugin source code, try doing a package specific config with the extension specific dest values and see if that works

Comment: @theaccordance I'll try that.

Comment: @theaccordance . Didn't work. I'm trying to figure out if I can debug the plugin code. I don't have a javascript debugger that I can run on the command line easily. I think I'm going to abandon this bower-grunt workflow.

Comment: It only takes a couple mins to do what you're trying to do with `grunt-bower` using `grunt-contrib-copy`, it's just not as automatic as one might want

Comment: I try to adhere to the 'dry' philosophy. Don't Repeat Yourself. I hate specifying the packages I need in one place. Then in another place, specify the same packages to be copied over.when I looked at contrib-copy it seemed like I would have to maintain 2 lists. It leaves more room for error.

Comment: @theaccordance npm + browserify is proving to be a much simpler way to accomplish what I want to do. I may have to go back and use grunt to uglify my JS for production deployment. But for now, grunt and bower are off the table.

I'm going to close this question. I don't feel that "I used something else" is a valuable answer to  anyone. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: If anything I've said was ever considered an Answer, it would have been posted as one and not a comment

Comment: @theaccordance . I meant my own resolution. That my eventual solution was to use a completely different workflow (npm and browersrfy), instead of bower and grunt. So people searching for an answer, and find this. Might not see it as helpful.